# Figure caption scientific names + symbols in textGrob gtable

Tags: r, ggplot2, caption, gtable

First of all I would like to thank Sir Baptiste for helping me improve my R script by adding a caption at the bottom left the of the combined plots using gtable/textGrob as shown below:

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- p2 <- ggplot()

g1 <- ggplotGrob(p1)
g2 <- ggplotGrob(p2)

g <- rbind(g1, g2)
caption <- textGrob("Figure 1. This is a caption", hjust=0, x=0)
g <- gtable::gtable_add_rows(g, unit(2,"mm") + grobHeight(caption), -1)
g <- gtable::gtable_add_grob(g, caption, nrow(g), l = 4, r = ncol(g))
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

However, I want to add two more things:

(1) Insert a scientific name to the caption, which should be written in italics. 
 - For example, based on the caption mentioned above, I want to italize only the word "is" while the rest are in plain text.

(2) I will also add symbols in the caption, e.g. point shapes=c(1,22); colours=c("black", "red"); fill=c("red", "black").

How am I going to do these? I am a novice user of R program, hence your help is much appreciated. Thank you.

UPDATE:

I have already addressed query 1 with the help of @Docconcoct, @user20650 and @baptiste using this script:

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

g1 <- ggplotGrob(pl)
g2 <- ggplotGrob(pl1)

g <- rbind(g1, g2)
caption <- textGrob(expression(paste("Figure 1. This",  italic(" is"), " a caption")), hjust=0, x=0)
g <- gtable::gtable_add_rows(g, unit(2,"mm") + grobHeight(caption), -1)
g <- gtable::gtable_add_grob(g, caption, nrow(g), l = 4, r = ncol(g))
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

For query 2,  as stated by Sir @baptiste, in my original email to him, I already have a legend on the combined plots. However, in the figure caption, I need to state what are those symbols in the legend mean, and some other details of the plot. Based on the example given by Sir baptiste, I need to include what supp means, as well as the symbols of OJ (dark circle) and VC (dark triangle) in the caption.

Again, many thanks!

Comment: The following should result in italics as described:

`caption <- textGrob(expression(atop("Figure 1. This ", atop(italic("is ")), "a caption", hjust=0, x=0)))`

I'd advise you to create reproducible data with dput() and add it to your question. At the moment it is unclear what your output should look like and I'm not clear on what it is you want for number 2.

Comment: I should probably mention that what you're trying to do is not trivial, so unless someone volunteers to do all the coding for you, with all the fiddly little details to get exactly the plot you want, you'll have to spend some time learning about low-level gtable and grid functions. Alternatively, you could consider other ways to make a figure caption, e..g with LaTeX or some text editor. It might be easier for a one-off project.

Comment: As a side-note, most of the time figure captions refer to the symbols with a text-only description, not with pictures (but I do see potential value in that approach). Your caption would typically read something like, "Figure 1. The red points correspond to data set 1984, while open squares are from John et al. [37]."

Comment: [this latex question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102925/9459) may be relevant too

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments, I suggest the following strategy: create a dummy plot with your figure caption (text) as legend title, extract its legend, and place it at the bottom of your gtable.

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)

p1 <- ggplot()
p2 <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(len, dose, shape=supp)) + geom_point() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", 
        legend.background=element_rect(colour="black")) 

title <- expression("Figure 1. This "*italic(is)*" now a legendary caption")
dummy <- ggplotGrob(p2 + guides(shape = guide_legend(title = title)))

g1 <- ggplotGrob(p1)
g2 <- ggplotGrob(p2)
caption <- gtable_filter(dummy,"guide")[["grobs"]][[1]]
caption$widths <- grid:::unit.list(caption$widths)
caption$widths <- unit.c(unit(0,"mm"), caption$widths[2], unit(1,"null"))

g <- rbind(g1, g2)
g <- gtable::gtable_add_rows(g, unit(2,"mm") + grobHeight(caption), -1)
g <- gtable::gtable_add_grob(g, caption, nrow(g), l = 4, r = ncol(g))
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(legend)
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Docconcoct and  user20650 for your help. I incorporated both your suggestions to get the output that I want in query 1, as presented by Sir baptiste as above. I also apologize for the confusion on what I really want to achieve on query 2. As stated by Sir baptiste, in my original email to him, I already have a legend on the combined plots. However, in the figure caption, I need to state again what are those symbols in the legend mean. Based on the example given by Sir baptiste above, I need to include the symbols of OJ (dark circle) and VC (dark triangle) in the caption. Thanks!

Comment: please update your question rather than clarifying it in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

I think a good solution would rely on LaTeX or similar for the text rendering and particularly the tricky issue of line-wrapping, but something could be designed at R level to facilitate the inclusion of plotting symbols that correspond to a given graphic. Something along those lines,

```
gl = extract_legend_grobs(p)
caption = caption_plot("Figure 1. We are referring to the points {{gl$points[supp == OG'']}}. 
 The theoretical model is shown as {{gl$lines[type == 'theory']}}.", gl)

print(caption, output="latex")
## "Figure 1. We are referring to the points \includegraphics{gl_p_1.png}. 
## The theoretical model is shown as \includegraphics{gl_l_1.png}."
```

Interesting thought, but probably a lot of work to get it right.

A quick-and-dirty R graphics output could also be devised, though it's uncommon to want captions to be part of the figure (and R graphics isn't particularly good with text).

Here's a weak attempt at making a caption grob mixing symbols and text. Ideally the text would be split into individual words first (to offer more options for line breaks), but plotmath expressions make it inconvenient.

[image]

Next step would be to add a few convenient wrappers to generate common symbols, and to interleave the two lists of grobs.

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

inwidth <- function(x, margin=unit(1,"mm")) {
  if(inherits(x, "text"))
    convertWidth(grobWidth(x)+margin, "in", valueOnly = TRUE) else
      convertWidth(unit(1,"line")+margin, "in", valueOnly = TRUE)
}

captionGrob <- function(..., width = unit(4, "in"), debug = FALSE){

  maxw <- convertWidth(width, "in", valueOnly = TRUE)
  lg <- list(...)
  lw <- lapply(lg, inwidth)
  stopifnot(all(lw < maxw))

  # find breaks
  cw <- cumsum(lw)
  bks <- which(c(0, diff(cw %% maxw))  < 0 )
  # list of lines
  tg <- list()
  starts <- c(1, bks)
  ends <- c(bks -1, length(lg))

  for(line in seq_along(starts)){
    ids <- seq(starts[line], ends[line])
    sumw <- do.call(sum,lw[ids])
    neww <- maxw - sumw # missing width to fill
    filler <- rectGrob(gp=gpar(col=NA, fill=NA), 
                             width=unit(neww, "in"), 
                             height=unit(1, "line"))
    grobs <- c(lg[ids], list(filler))

    # store current line
    tg[[line]] <- arrangeGrob(grobs=grobs, nrow = 1, 
                              widths = unit(c(lw[ids], neww), "in"))

  }

  # arrange all lines in one column
  grid.arrange(grobs=tg, ncol=1,
               heights = unit(rep(1, length(tg)), "line"))

  if(debug)  grid.rect(width=width, gp=gpar(fill=NA, lty=2))
}

tg <- lapply(c(expression(bold(Figure~1.)~italic(Those)~points), 
               "are important, ", "nonetheless", "and", "have value too."), 
             textGrob)
pGrob <- function(fill, size=1, ...){
  rectGrob(..., width=unit(size,"line"), height=unit(size,"line"), gp=gpar(fill=fill))
}
pg <- mapply(pGrob, fill=1:5, size=0.5, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
grid.newpage()
captionGrob(tg[[1]], pg[[1]], pg[[2]], pg[[3]], tg[[2]], tg[[3]], pg[[4]], tg[[4]], pg[[5]], tg[[5]])
```

Comment: Thank you Sir baptiste for your suggestions. I will just try and check which of these will work for me. I will try to learn and understand each element, as I have mentioned, I am quite new to R program. I really appreciate all your time and efforts to help me. I'll come back when I finished figuring it out. Again, please accept my sincere appreciation.

Comment: if anyone's interested in pursuing this idea, I've sketched some ideas [in this github repo](https://github.com/baptiste/caption)

Comment: This is more straightforward than the previous one. But I am not sure how to insert this to my previous script. Thank you for this Sir Baptiste! :)