# How to use the symbols and colors of a ggplot into a figure caption in LaTeX?

Tags: r, text, ggplot2, latex, caption

I'm writng a paper and I'm using R for my plots. The journal guidelines say that the legend of the plot must be in the figure caption. So I want to know if it's possible and how to use the R symbols and colors into a caption in LaTeX?

Additionally, the  red circle is not appearing in the compiled document.

Plot in R

```
library(ggplot2)

A <- seq(0, 10, by = 1)
B <- seq(0, 20, by = 2)
C <- seq(0, 30, by = 3)

DF <- data.frame(A, B, C)

pdf(
  file = "Figure1.pdf",
  width = 8/2.54,
  height = 5/2.54,
  pointsize = 8
)
ggplot(data = DF) +
  geom_point(aes(x = 0:10, y = A, color = "A", shape = "A")) +
  geom_point(aes(x = 0:10, y = B, color = "B", shape = "B")) +
  geom_point(aes(x = 0:10, y = C, color = "C", shape = "C")) +
  scale_shape_manual(name = "Legend", values = c(0, 1, 2)) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Legend", values = c("black", "red", "blue"))

dev.off()
```

[image]

LaTeX document

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, twocolumns]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
This is a test\par
%
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics{Figure1.pdf}
\caption{I want here the symbols and colors that were used in R}
\label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Any Help?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35936319/471093 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102925/how-can-i-insert-the-symbols-into-the-caption-of-a-figure  https://github.com/baptiste/caption

Answer (score 1):

I would just find the corresponding symbols in LaTeX and add the coloring manually. I can recommend [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) for finding the symbols. The triangle-symbol can be found like this:

[image: Like this]